# Crystal Reports - Where clause in formula to calculate sum of a field from second table

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to get a result in my report, which I beleive, requires a where clause and did not work for me with the select expert section.

I have 2 tables. Lets call them table 1 and table 2.

Table 1 contains **unique** records.

Table 2 contains **multiple** records for the same uniqueKey as table 1.

there are 3 fields in table 2 that play a roll for each uniqueKey from table 1.

1. QTY_ORD
2. QTY_SHIPPED
3. ITEM_CANCEL

Lets assume for item # 1 from table 1, there are 5 records in table 2. Each record has a values for the 3 above mentioned fields. I need to display the SUM of all the records where ITEM_CANCEL = 0 of QTY_SHIPPED - QTY_ORD.

It could be that 3 of the records have ITEM_CANCEL = 1 (We can ignore these records), but for the other 2 reocrds where ITEM_CANCEL = 0, I need the SUM of QTY_SHIPPED - SUM of QTY_ORD.

the current code I have is as follows"

```
if {current_order1.ITEM_CANCEL} = 0 then
sum({current_order1.QTY_ORD})-sum({current_order1.QTY_SHIPPED}) else
0
```

but this result gives me the sum of ALL the records, including the ones where ITEM_CANCEL = 1.

If I use ITEM_CANCEL = 0 in the select expert, then it removes ALL the results that have no value in table 2. I even tried the code without using the SUM function, but this provided the result of only 1 of the records in table 2 where ITEM_CANCEL = 0, and not the total difference of the 2 records in table 2 that I require.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a detail-level formuls (no SUM):

`if {current_order1.ITEM_CANCEL} = 0 then {current_order1.QTY_ORD} - {current_order1.QTY_SHIPPED} ELSE 0`

Then, SUM that formula at whatever Group or Report levels you require.